# Can a Google for Work account be changed to a personal account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I'm tired of running into the limitations of having my account as a "Google for Work" account and would like to convert it to a personal account. Is this possible?

If not, is there any way to migrate the current email address along with Google Play, Google Apps and other and so on to another account?

Comment: By «personal account», do you mean an `@gmail.com` account?

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I did get an answer from a Google rep yesterday. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: There are several questions here about migrated data from one Google Account to another. Check them out for solutions to get your data from one to the other. I'm afraid you might be stuck with purchases from the Google Play Store. As far as I know, they're not transferable.

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from Google. Seems like it isn't possible.

> ... you'll need to delete your Google for Work account and create an
>   email address using your custom domain through a different provider so
>   you can have an email account using this domain name. Please have in
>   mind that when deleting the account, all the data inside of it will be
>   deleted too.
>
> There isn't any option on Google for Work to convert it into a
>   personal account, however, once you create your email address through
>   a different provider, you can sign up for a Google account using that
>   email address (check this link for more info: http://goo.gl/QPnwxl ),
>   this will allow you to use any Google service (except Gmail). Please
>   make sure you completely delete your Google for Work account (as this
>   article describes: http://goo.gl/RbFrZl ) before creating the email
>   address through a different provider. -VS

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no real way to do this.  You must be willing to lose Google Play purchases which is a huge bummer.  The second inconvenience is that you will need to migrate all of your information to the personal account.

Given that you will likely have a LOT less data capacity in the personal account, you may need to purchase storage before doing so.  You should either use Takeout or a third-party migration app for Google to move your data.